# The subdivision modifier destroyed the flat surface

Tags: faces, subdivision-surface

[image]

This part of my sub should be flat but after the subdivision modifier, it became strange and far from flat.

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use edge creasing to keep the border from being affected by subsurf : select the border edges and either hit shift+E & drag, or increase the "crease" property in the sidebar ("transform" tab).

Comment: Thanks, Hadriscus!